# Is possible to force docker compose to create aws ecs service as blue/green?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, blue-green-deployment

I'm using docker compose to create resources in aws and using `x-aws-cloudformation` extension to change somethings but I had to create a aws codepipeline with blue/green (to avoid down time) but looks like that `x-aws-cloudformation` extension haven't support to blue/green ... Tried to set the `DeploymentControler` to `CODE_DEPLOY` in ecs service but it fails.

Well someone knows if is possible to set it in docker compose? I wouldn't like to do it manually or use CloudFormation.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Also, unfortunately, docker-compose dropped all support for ECS deployments back in November https://docs.docker.com/cloud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Docker Compose AWS integration, particularly through the Docker ECS integration (which allows you to deploy Docker containers on AWS ECS using Docker Compose files), has limited support for some specific AWS features, including the advanced deployment strategies like Blue/Green deployments facilitated by AWS CodeDeploy.

So you can use AWS CLI commands, AWS SDK scripts or even Terraform templates to adjust your deployment process. This could involve scripting the creation and management of CodeDeploy configurations that handle the Blue/Green deployment process outside of the Docker Compose workflow. This option would provide you more flexibility and greater and quicker support to new features introduced.